# java script помогите разобраться с маской ввода времени

Tags: javascript

Не могу нигде найти код маски ввода на чистом JS БЕЗ использования jquery (принципиально не нравится эта библиотека), есть у кого нибудь что то подобное или подскажите хотя бы логику написания, уже всю голову сломал.

Нужна маска ввода времени в поле инпут. Валидация с помощью регулярного выражения получается а вот запретить ввод ненужных символов и разрешить ввод нужных не выходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<input
    type="text"
    name="date"
    placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"
    onkeyup="
        var v = this.value;
        if (v.match(/^\d{2}$/) !== null) {
            this.value = v + '/';
        } else if (v.match(/^\d{2}\/\d{2}$/) !== null) {
            this.value = v + '/';
        }"
    maxlength="10"
>

<input
    type="text"
    name="date"
    placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"
    onkeyup="
        var v = this.value;
        if (v.match(/^\d{2}$/) !== null) {
            this.value = v + '/';
        } else if (v.match(/^\d{2}\/\d{2}$/) !== null) {
            this.value = v + '/';
        }"
    maxlength="10"
>
<input
    type="text"
    name="date"
    placeholder="yyyy/mm/dd"
    onkeyup="
        var v = this.value;
        if (v.match(/^\d{4}$/) !== null) {
            this.value = v + '/';
        } else if (v.match(/^\d{4}\/\d{2}$/) !== null) {
            this.value = v + '/';
        }"
    maxlength="10"
>
<input
    type="text"
    name="date"
    placeholder="yyyy年mm月dd"
    onkeyup="
        var v = this.value;
        if (v.match(/^\d{4}$/) !== null) {
            this.value = v + '年';
        } else if (v.match(/^\d{4}年\d{2}$/) !== null) {
            this.value = v + '月';
        }"
    maxlength="10"
>
```

Comment: спасибо, все работает супер, а есть ли еще способ удалять символы одиночным нажатием бэкспейс? не все могут догадаться удерживать его=)